# Reference error for _ (lodash) when declared as peerDependency

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, lodash

I have my custom lib which is published via npm. It declares peerDependency `"lodash": "4.15.*"`

As far as I understand, that means that whoever want to use my lib should provide `lodash` with specified version. So in my app in npm dependencies I have `"lodash": "4.15.*"` but when using component from my custom lib I receive following `ReferenceError: _ is not defined`.
I have also added `require('lodash');` to my `app.js` but it didn't help.

What else should I do in order to make this work?

Library is written in AngularJS 1.5 and TypeScript. I am trying to use it with plain AngularJS 1.5 application.

EDIT.

In my library I assume, that variable `_` is global, so it isn't imported in any file that uses it.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski Unfortunately  `var _ = require('lodash')` Didn't make any difference.

Comment: Are you trying to load Lodash client- or server-side? NPM can be used for client-side dependencies, but generally only when also using a build tool, like Browserify or Webpack, that can translate Node's module system so a browser can understand what's supposed to happen.

Comment: I am trying to load Lodash on client-side. Yes I am using Browserify to put all my scripts into single file.

Comment: `peerDependencies` don't affect anything in NPM 3. Why Lodash should be defined as peer dependency? Angular is peer dependency for Angular library. Lodash is simply dependency.

Comment: @estus It's legacy issue. But if I don't find solution soon, it will be probably better to change library dependencies.

Comment: You won't. Peer dependencies are deprecated in current NPM version and exist only as an reminder that you need to have these packages installed alongside with dependent one. It is obvious when it is `angular` dependency for Angular library. It isn't obvious if it is Lodash.

Comment: @estus Thanks, than I will go and change library dependencies. You can post it as an answer. 
EDIT. It didn't solve the problem unfortunately.

Comment: This totally depends on the details of your build. If you use npm dependencies in your package, you should use `var _ = require('lodash')` in each place where `_` is used. When the app is built with Browserify, there's no `_` global.

Comment: Ok, I have modified library, so `_` is no longer needed as global variable. Problem solved. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assumption that `_` is global is incorrect. If you are using the npm version of lodash, it is a commonjs module which will not globally export anything.

This means, that unless you are using some special plugin in browserify to export `_` globally, or you are including lodash from a cdn using a script tag, `_` will not be defined.

Assuming you are using typescript 2.0 and have installed the `@types/lodash` npm package, then the correct way to import lodash in every script that needs to use it is:

```
import * as _ from 'lodash';
```

This will transpile as:

```
var _ = require('lodash')
```

Which should be enough for node (or `browserify` when using it in web) to properly include and set `_` to be usable.